# Long text scroll in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to scroll long text in one line (right to left) i JavaScript.

Currently I doing it by change margin-left with timer.

```
        //Change Margin
    $('#sliderContentText').css('margin-left', -sliderOptions.currentMargin);
    sliderOptions.currentMargin=sliderOptions.currentMargin+sliderOptions.marginSpeed;
```

There is any other way to do this?

The problem is if I change margin every 10 ms by 1 there is a lot CPU consumption.

Comment: You looking for an Javascript solution, right? Then this is a way which you can choose. Otherwise to prevent cross browser problems, you can use a jQuery plugin or something else.

Comment: Any solution with low memory consumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use margin for that purpose ([see why](http://jsbin.com/cefux/1/edit)) ... you can use [relative position](http://jsbin.com/cefux/2/edit) ...

or the best solution:  **[relative position + css transitions](http://jsbin.com/cefux/5/edit)**

**JS**

```
var s = $('#sliderContentText');

setInterval(function(){
  s.toggleClass('moveleft');
},1000);
```

**CSS**

```
#sliderContentText {
  position: relative;
  transition: left 1s;
  left: 0;
}
#sliderContentText.moveleft {
  left: 50px;
}
```

you should always store jquery elements outside function loops to avoid memory consumption

Comment: Great. But how to make by transition to always move left?

Comment: instead of toggleClass in an interval, just do a single addClass.